# Add quantity button to increase/decrease quantity as well as change database and decrease the quantity from total stocks

Tags: python, html, django-models, django-views

I want to add quantity feature in my form and model in which I want to update the quantity from the total quantity in the stocks and quantity will be decrease if we add quantity in of any product, ...
suppose we have 50 t-shirt stock and customer added 5 so the total quantity will be 45 in stocks.

```
 models.py

# models.py
from collections.abc import Collection
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def clean_mobile(self):
        mobile=self.mobile
        if len(str(mobile))!= 10:
            raise ValidationError("invalid mobile number")
        return mobile

class Supplier(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name

views.py

@login_required
def supplier_dashboard(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        product_name=request.POST.get('product_name')
        product_price=request.POST.get('product_price')
        image=request.FILES.get('image')
    

data=Supplier.objects.create(user=request.user,product_name=product_name,product_price=product_price,image=image)
    data.save()
    supplier=Supplier.objects.filter(user=request.user)
else:
    supplier=Supplier.objects.filter(user=request.user)
return render(request, 'enroll/supplier_dashboard.html',{'suppliers':supplier})


supplier_dashboard.html


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>supplier_dashboard</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <h1><u>WELCOME TO YOUR PROFILE</u></h1>
        <font color="red" size="8">{{request.user.username}} </font>
        <div>   
            {%if messages%}
            {% for message in messages%}
            <div id="message_container" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show text-center" role="alert">
                **{{message}}**
    
            </div>
            {%endfor%}
            {%endif%}
        </div>
    </div>



    <h1 class="text-center alert alert-info">Customer Dashboard</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h1 class="text-center alert alert-info">Add Product</h1>
            <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="product_name">Product Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="product_name" class="form-control" name="product_name" required><br>

                <label for="product_price">Product Price:</label>
                <input type="text" id="product_price" class="form-control" name="product_price" required><br>

                <label for="supplier_images">Image:</label>
                <input type="file" name="image" reuired><br><br>

                <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-success">
            </form>
            <br><br>
            <h3>
                <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="btn btn-success">Logout</a>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <h1 class="text-center alert alert-info">Order Details</h1>

            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Customer Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Product Price</th>
                        <th scope="col">Product Image</th>
                        <th scope="col">Action</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    {% for supplier in suppliers %}
                    <tr>

                        <td scope="row">{{supplier.user}}</td>
                        <td scope="row">{{supplier.product_name}}</td>
                        <td scope="row">{{supplier.product_price}}</td>
                        <td scope="row"><img src="{{supplier.image.url}}" alt="image" style="height: 50px;width:50px"></td>
                        <td scope="row">
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                                <a href="{% url 'supplier_edit' supplier.id %}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                                <a href="{% url 'supplier_delete' supplier.id %}" class="btn btn-danger"  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')">Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        // suppose the `id` attribute of element is `message_container`.
        var message_ele = document.getElementById("message_container");

        setTimeout(function () {
            message_ele.style.display = "none";
        }, 5000);
        // Timeout is 3 sec, you can change it

        



    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please *don't* write a title in *all caps*: all caps are considered "screaming" on the internet, and is seen as "rude".

Comment: Also what is the question? What works and what does not work here?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)